# Type deduction does not work with std::function

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have the following problem. When I try to compile the following code

```
template< typename T >
T func( T t)
{
  return t;
}

template< size_t N, typename T >
void foo( std::function< T(T) > func )
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  foo<3>( func<float> );

  return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

```
 no matching function for call to 'foo'
      foo<3>( func<float> );
      ^~~~~~
/Users/arirasch/WWU/dev/xcode/tests/tests/main.cpp:18:10: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-1 (type-parameter-0-1)>' against 'float (*)(float)'
    void foo( std::function< T(T) > func )
```

However, when I fix it to

```
template< typename T >
T func( T t)
{
  return t;
}

template< size_t N, typename T >
void foo( std::function< T(T) > func )
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{

  std::function< float(float) > input_func = func<float>;
  foo<3>( input_func );

  return 0;
}
```

i.e., when I declare the input function of `foo` explicitly as `std::function< float(float) >`, the compilation can be done successfully.

Does anyone know how I can fixe my code alternatively so that I can simply write something like `foo<3>( func<float> );` (according to my first code example) instead of

```
std::function< float(float) > input_func = func<float>;
foo<3>( input_func );
```

where the type of `input_func` must be explicitly stated?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Functions aren't `std::function`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type deduction does not work in your case simply because it cannot be deduced. Type deduction is, in most cases, a simple match with types and other template parameters. There is however some dark corner of C++ that deal with deduction that has some funky rules, but I won't go into it for this answer.

This is an example where the compiler can deduce template arguments:

```
template<typename T>
void test(std::vector<T>);

test(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
```

This is easy for the compiler. It need a `std::vector` of `T`. You give it a `std::vector` of `int`. `T` must be `int`.

However, in your case, There is a lot more stuff happening:

```
template<typename T>
void test(std::function<T(T)>);

int someFunc(int);

test(someFunc);
```

The compiler can't do the match. Try for yourself: Give me a `T` that will make those two types equal: `int(*)(int)` to `std::function<T(T)>`. Indeed, there is no possible `T` that can make those two type to be the same, whereas the vector version was an easy match.

You will say to me: "but... a pointer to a function is convertible to a std::function you silly!" Yeah, it is convertible, indeed. But before any conversion, the compiler *has* to find what `T` is. Without `T`, you make the conversion from a pointer to function to what class? Many class? Try to match every `T`? There is multiple possibility where your function would be convertible.

---

How  can you make this work? Forget the `std::function`. Just receive `T`.

```
template<typename T>
T func(T t) {
  return t;
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
void foo(T func) {
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  foo<3>( func<float> );

  return 0;
}
```

Notice how this example works well. You have no conversion, no `std::function` thingy and can work with any callable you can possibly imagine!

Are you worried about accepting any type? No worry here! Parameter types are a bad way to express what a template can do with received parameters anyway. You should restrict it with an *expression*. That expression will tell others how you will use `T` and what interface `T` need to have. btw, we call that sfinae:

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
auto foo(T func) -> decltype(void(func(std::declval<int>()))) {
  // ...
}
```

In this example, you restrict `func` to be callable with a `int` and still return `void`.

Comment: "Type deduction is a simple match ..." Well, no. Just have a peek at the list of places in which it occurs, and what deduced contexts exist. It's a testament to the C++ language that you _think_ it's simple, though.

Comment: So i don't really get why you are using void_t? I tried it without, and it also worked. Could you maybe elaborate.

Comment: @Dimfred This is because the trailing return type `decltype(func(...))` will change the return type of `foo`, which is maybe not what you want. `void_t<decltype(...)>` or `decltype(void(...))` will ensure foo has a `void` return type.

Comment: Okay I see, that is very interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the compiler must do overload resolution to find out which `std::function<U(U)>` instantiations have constructor(s) that can take a `T(*)(T)`. That is to say, there might be multiple types each of which may have multiple ctors that could take your `input_func`.

Now, if you look at the Standard, you'll find that there is no such overload specified for `std::function`, but the overload resolution rules are the same for all templates, whether they're from `std::`, `boost::` or `ACME::`. The compiler won't start instantiating templates to find a conversion sequence.

Once you provide a perfect match, there's no need for a conversion sequence. There's exactly one target type for which no conversion sequence is needed, and the compiler deduces this type.

In this particular case, you know about the relation between function pointers and `std::function`, and also about the specific restriction that you must have a unitary function which returns the same type (no `T(*)(U)`) so you could add an overload

```
template< size_t N, typename T >
void foo(T(*func)(T))
{
  return foo<N>(std::function<T(T)>(func));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting func to an std::function explicitly solves the problem. E.g. the code below works.

```
template< typename T >
T func( T t)
{
  return t;
}

template<typename T>
using FuncType = std::function<T(T)>;

template< size_t N, typename T >
void foo( FuncType<T> func )
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  func<float>(1.0);
  foo<3>( FuncType<float>(func<float>) );

  return 0;
}
```