# How to make a function template that takes a functor with variable arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

I'm trying to implement a function template (in C++11) whose parameter is a lambda with arbitrary parameters, and return a compatible std::function object. The goal is for the returned function when called to invoke the original lambda asynchronously, but for now I'm just returning the original lambda.

The problem is simply getting the compiler to accept a lambda as the parameter of the function template. Here are some simple templates:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <class Arg>
function<void(Arg)> pass1(function<void(Arg)> fn) {
    return fn;
}

template <class... Args>
function<void(Args...)> passn(function<void(Args...)> fn) {
    return fn;
}
```

They do the same thing, it's just that `pass1` only works on single-parameter functors while `passn` takes an arbitrary number.

So now we try using them, first `pass1`:

```
    auto p1 = pass1( [](int a)->void {cout << a;} );  // ERROR
```

This doesn't work; the compiler can't seem to tell what parameters the lambda takes. Clang error message is:

```
Untitled.cpp:17:12: error: no matching function for call to 'pass1'
    auto p1 = pass1( [](int a)->void {cout << a;} );
              ^~~~~
Untitled.cpp:6:21: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (type-parameter-0-0)>' against '(lambda at Untitled.cpp:17:19)'
function<void(Arg)> pass1(function<void(Arg)> fn) {
```

I can work around this by explicitly specifying the template parameter type:

```
    auto p2 = pass1<int>( [](int a)->void {cout << a;} );  // OK
```

However, this workaround fails with `passn`:

```
    auto p3 = passn<int>( [](int a)->void {cout << a;} );

Untitled.cpp:23:12: error: no matching function for call to 'passn'
    auto p3 = passn<int>( [](int a)->void {cout << a;} );
              ^~~~~~~~~~
Untitled.cpp:11:25: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (int, type-parameter-0-0...)>' against '(lambda at Untitled.cpp:23:24)'
function<void(Args...)> passn(function<void(Args...)> fn) {
                    ^
```

The weird thing is that I *can* invoke `passn` if I pass it a `function` object:

```
    function<void(int)> fn = [](int a)->void {cout << a;};
    auto x = passn<int>(fn);  // OK
```

...in fact, I don't even have to specify the template parameter type:

```
    auto y = passn(fn);  // OK
```

The function I actually need is going to be like `passn`, but I don't want the extra verbiage of having to wrap a `function` object around the lambda every time I call it. Am I missing something, or is this just not possible? Would it be possible in C++14?

Comment: you can simply wrap a `std::function` around the lambda at the call site, or as the dupe shows, change pass1/passn to accept general templates and restrict them with decltype if you must.

Comment: @TemplateRex No problem, thanks for reopening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type deduction does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086513/type-deduction-does-not-work)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this implementation of `passn`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class RetVal, class T, class... Args>
std::function<RetVal(Args...)> get_fun_type(RetVal (T::*)(Args...) const);

template <class RetVal, class T, class... Args>
std::function<RetVal(Args...)> get_fun_type(RetVal (T::*)(Args...));

template <class T>
auto passn(T t) -> decltype(get_fun_type(&T::operator())) {
    return t;
}

int main() {
    auto fun = passn([](int a) { std::cout << a; });
    fun(42);
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96c0b48a1733fc84))

It assumes you pass in a type that has an `operator()`. It takes the address of that function and deduces parameters from that member pointer.

The function will fail if you pass it an object that has multiple `operator()`s because then taking its address will be ambiguous, but lambdas will not produce that problem.

Comment: If you come here from the future and have access to C++17, deduction guides [4:28 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3fVp0U4xi0) might be the better solution.